# Возможно ли запретить создание лямбды

Tags: java, интерфейс, java-8, лямбда-выражение

В проекте имеется обычный интерфейс с единственным метод. Он был создан еще на Java 5 и стал за это время довольно популярным.

И сейчас его семантика запрещает использовать его, как функциональный интерфейс, те. "создавать из него лямбду".

**Как же запретить использовать его, как лямбду?**

Лично мне никакие идею не приходят, за исключением использования аннотации. Также была идея генерировать исключение, но как не понятно???

Comment: Не могли бы Вы поподробнее рассказать про семантику? Вы хотите запретить реализацию интерфейса лямбдой/ссылкой на метод? Почему этому интерфейсу важно кто и как его реализует?

Comment: @defaultlocale у нас в проекте важно, что еще реализующий класс имеет (поля, методы и тд.) и по его содержимому определяется, как использовать его в конечном автомате (он построен по  паттерну State). А из - за того, что лямбда не позволить этого не может и для проекта она "сухая" и влечет ошибки.

Comment: Ситуация понятна. Но согласитесь проблема здесь не в лямбде. Человек и на Java 5 мог написать «сухую» реализацию интерфейса, без нужных полей и методов, и получить те же ошибки. Проблема в скрытых ожиданиях: интерфейс имеет один метод, а от него ожидают много всего другого.

Comment: Есть [похожий вопрос в английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067311/can-an-interface-somehow-prevent-lambda-expression-implementations), никто ничего путного не предложил. Вместо запрещения лямбды предлагаю рассмотреть изменение архитектуры (сделать интерфейс со всеми необходимыми методами), либо проверять все нужные поля/методы рефлексией, выдавая исключения (не найдено поле А).

Comment: Еще вариант: добавить метод в интерфейс, что сделает его нефункциональным. Проблему это не решит, но усложнит жизнь ленивым программистам :) Но придется переписывать код.

Comment: @defaultlocale соглашусь с вами и спасибо за предложенные варианты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема решилась путем полного пересмотра и передела архитектуры. Спасибо за решение [default locale](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178556/default-locale)!